# Stuck in a login-loop in lightdm and gdm, but not with xfce and other systems

Tags: ubuntu, login, xfce, gdm, lightdm

The interesting part is I found that I was able to login with xfce but not with either lightdm or gdm. (I am using Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you do something before this problem?
Maybe you run `.Xauthority` with sudo.
Log in using `CTRL+ALT+F1` and type:

```
sudo chown yourusername ~/.Xauthority
```

Comment: yes, I did. And It didn't change anything

Comment: now you are sure that the .Xauthority file has the user permission? Can you do that command again as root? What did you do before this problem?

Comment: Hi, in my case, I have a huge shared networks with multiple users, then I was creating a new one for my friend. I tried with so many solutions, but none of them seemed to work for me. Later, I had to work around by reinstall the Ubuntu.

Comment: I think I figured out my problem, since I am using network computers. After creating and modifying users int /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow. I also need to consider /etc/group /etc/auto.master (in autofs), so I can make sure my new user can be connected into the server.

Comment: Good if it works answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out my problem, since I am using network computers. After creating and modifying users int /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow. I also need to consider /etc/group /etc/auto.master (in autofs), so I can make sure my new user can be connected into the server.

However, I still don't have a clear explanation why xforce can work under error of /etc/passwd  and /etc/shadow